# How to send json message to sqs by using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I am beginner in Laravel. In my task, I need to do following points:-

1. In a controller, store contents of csv file in an array. --- Completed
2. In same controller, send step 1. array in json format to sqs (amazon) by using laravel. --- Pending
3. For step 2), I have set the config/queue.php

```
'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'xxxxx'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'ap-northeast-1'),
        ],
```

Also changed .env file

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx
SQS_QUEUE=data_queue_name_aws
```

2. Created a job 
   php artisan make:job SendMessageSQS
3. Call `SendMessageSQS::dispatch();`
4. SQS received message

```
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\SendMessageSQS","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"delay":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,
  "data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\SendMessageSQS","command":"O:21:\"App\\Jobs\\SendMessageSQS\":3:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000item\";s:7:\"testing\";s:10:\"connection\";
  s:7:\"sqs\";s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;}"}}
```

5. How to send

```
$userIDs = [1,2,3]; // array values from csv file column `user-is`
$sendMessageSqs["file-name"] = "test-sqs-1";
$sendMessageSqs["user-id"] = $userIDs;
```

6. Actual Result: SQS should store below format

```
{"file-name":"test-sqs-1","user-id":"1,2,3"}
```

Comment: This looks like a good question, but I advise against asking for "step by step" instructions here. Answerers will assist in any way they like - they are volunteers after all - but they won't know the exact nuances of your use case. It is the job of the question author to take hints from answers and apply them to their particular situation. Programming is not merely a matter of copy-and-paste - programmers should understand exactly what their code is doing.

Answer (score 14):

You can send a raw message:

```
Queue::connection('sqs')->pushRaw('payload_body', 'queue_name');
```

In general, it calls `SqsQueue->pushRaw` method which calls `SqsClient` from `aws-sdk-php` which actually sends a message

Comment: if you want to use queue name on the .env file (SQS_QUEUE) you can call Queue::connection('sqs')->pushRaw('body');

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't possible with standard laravel queues. The extra metadata you are seeing in the job is so that the job can be handled and routed correctly by laravel, models can be unserialized, etc.

You can either push raw messages directly to the queue the `aws-sdk` library, or you can use a package such as the one below which implements a custom queue driver.

https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-plain-sqs

Comment: Hi Atymic,
Thanks for your quick reply.
I tried but displaying error

"There is no existing directory at "/Users/smartshopping/workspace/laravel-projects/smartsearch-datasale/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied"

Comment: Above issue There is no existing directory at "xyz/storage/logs" and its not buildable is resolved from `php artisan optimize:clear`. But getting this error

Method Dusterio\PlainSqs\Jobs\DispatcherJob::handle() does not exist

Comment: I added handle() function in vendor/dusterio/laravel-plain-sqs/src/Jobs/DispatcherJob.php.

Now, there is no error but in sqs no message is received.